# iOS Successive TCP Requests Fail

Tags: c#, ios, tcp

I am currently developing an iOS app which uses CFStream to communicate with a C# server. Sending 1 TCP packet over this connection does what its supposed to. However, if I try to send two packets, they both fail.

The server is designed to be asynchronous like the one [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx). The iOS side is designed using the CFStream classes, as dictated in [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server) tutorial.

Why does this occur and how can I fix it? All help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I have just tried replacing the C# server with a Python server, and the system worked flawlessly, which would hint that the problem is server-side. Maybe the server is accidentally closing the connection after receiving the first packet?

Comment: I guess first step would be to determine where the problem is. Is it on the server or the client side? For example: can you transmit several messages to server via telnet?

Comment: It is probably client side. The server side command line tells me that it only receives the first TCP packet, it doesn't even get the second. The telnet test shows the server is working fine.

Comment: Can you try binding send function to some extra button. Can you send multiple packets this way? I'm asking because i think that you're trying to send second packet while first one is still being send thus ending in corruption of send buffer.

Comment: That would make sense, but I just tried it. The first button click went through, but when I clicked it again, the server didn't even receive a packet. If it means anything, I am getting an NSStreamEvent code 16 on the second request, but not the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the server was set up to close the connection after it sent its first packet of information to the client. The solution was to add a

```
handler.BeginReceive( state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
```

in the ReadCallback() method, to ensure it would resume listening to the client after processing its request.

Answer (score 1):

Start by figuring out for sure who is closing the TCP socket. Run [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) on the server to check who is sending a FIN or RST in that connection. That will split the problem in half.

Comment: I have just figured out it was the server. I was looking closer at MSDN's example, and it turns out the server closes the connection immediately after receiving a message. I will be posting the solution code shortly